# Get Row Count from Repeater Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to apply deletion of a column in a repeater for each item in it.  So far I've been able to apply that change in the Header Cell of that column, and also to the first row after the Header if  I put my code like this:

```
   protected void rptBillHeaders_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        RepeaterItem item = e.Item;
        if (item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            Repeater rptLineItems = ((Repeater)item.FindControl("rptLineItems"));
            rptLineItems.DataSource = currentBill.LineItemsByXVersion[rowNumber].Sort(BillLineItem.SortColumn.LineItemNumber, System.Data.SqlClient.SortOrder.Ascending);
            rptLineItems.DataBind();

            rowNumber++;

            if (e.Item.Controls.Count >= 5)
            {

                    var XDocColumn = (HtmlTableCell)e.Item.Controls[1];
                    if (lit.BillTypes.COD == "COD")
                    {
                        if (XDocColumn != null)
                        {
                            XDocColumn.Visible = false;
                        }
                    }

                 }
             }
        }
```

I assume that I need to get the Repeaters Count in order to iterate through the rows that the repeater is binding in order for me to achieve that solution. However, every time I run the application with a for loop I get:

```
 An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException'
 occurred in F_GBA.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Unable to 
cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.DataBoundLiteralControl'
to type 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableCell'.
```

Here's the code snippet:

```
 protected void rptBillHeaders_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        RepeaterItem item = e.Item;
        if (item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            Repeater rptLineItems = ((Repeater)item.FindControl("rptLineItems"));
            rptLineItems.DataSource = currentBill.LineItemsByXVersion[rowNumber].Sort(BillLineItem.SortColumn.LineItemNumber, System.Data.SqlClient.SortOrder.Ascending);
            rptLineItems.DataBind();

            if (e.Item.Controls.Count >= 5)
            {                   
                for (int i = 1; i <= item.Controls.Count; i++)
                {
                    var XDocColumn = (HtmlTableCell)e.Item.Controls[i];
                    if (lit.BillTypes.COD == "COD")
                    {
                        if (XDocColumn != null)
                        {
                            XDocColumn.Visible = false;
                        }
                    }
                }

            }

            rowNumber++;
        }
}
```

Mark - up code:

```
 <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptBillHeaders" OnItemDataBound="rptBillHeaders_ItemDataBound">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table width="98%" align="center" class="grid" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border:solid 1px #000000; border-top:none 0px #FFFFFF;">
                <tr class="gridHeaderRow">
                    <th>&nbsp</th>
                    <th><asp:Label runat="server" ID="billVersionLabel" ></asp:Label></th> 
                    <th>Action Type</th>
                    <th id="XDocHeader" runat="server">FMMI Doc #</th>
                    <th>X Status</th>
                    <th>Total Amount</th>
                    <th>Submitted By</th>
                    <th>Date Submitted</th>
                    <th>Date Processed</th>
                </tr>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr class="gridRow gridRowThickTopBorder">
            <td style="padding: 5px;">
                    <div id="divBillIcon" align="center" style="text-align:center;" class="icon ui-state-default ui-corner-all">
                        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-plus"></span>
                    </div>
            </td>
            <td class="Center"><%# ((int)Container.DataItem) %></td>
            <td><%# GetXActionType((int)Container.DataItem) %> </td>
            <td id="XDocColumn" runat="server"><%# GetXDocNumber((int)Container.DataItem) %> </td>
            <%--<td><%# val.get(cache.XStatusDict, currentBill.ProcessedStatusesByXVersion[((int)Container.DataItem)].XStatus, "&nbsp;") %></td>--%>
            <td><%# val.get(cache.BillStatusDict, currentBill.ProcessedStatusesByXVersion[((int)Container.DataItem)].XStatus, "&nbsp;") %></td>
            <td class="Right">$<%# currentBill.LineItemsByXVersion[((int)Container.DataItem)].GetTotalAmount().ToString("N2") %></td>
            <td><%# currentBill.PendingStatusesByXVersion[((int)Container.DataItem)].CreateWebUserName %></td>
            <td><%# convert.ToDateString(convert.ToDateTimeQ(currentBill.PendingStatusesByXVersion[((int)Container.DataItem)].CreateDate)) %></td>
            <td><%# convert.ToDateString(convert.ToDateTimeQ(currentBill.ProcessedStatusesByXVersion[((int)Container.DataItem)].CreateDate)) %></td>
        </tr>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You're just trying to hide a column? Why not do that on the client side with CSS and JavaScript? Do you really need the server to be involved?

Comment: Good suggestion, can you suggest a possible solution to achieve that through the client side?

Comment: You should probably post some of the markup as well to show us what that looks like. With just the code behind, I'm mostly making a guess. But you are casting a DataBoundLiteralControl as an HtmlTableCell. Try this instead: `foreach(Control XDocColumn in item.Controls)`

Comment: @BoydP Markup added. Thanks for the suggestion, I attempted to do as you said and now the second row appears, but no the first one (the one had deleted the column).

Comment: Explaining how to do it with CSS and JavaScript would be too broad. Instead, you should make your own attempt at it, and then if you get stuck that would be a good question for you to ask about, if you provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It looks like you are learning asp.net from your posts.  If that is the case and if you have a choice I would strongly suggest learning MVC over webforms for your overall professional benefit.  Pluralsight has some nice intro to MVC courses for free.

Comment: @Adam Heeg, thank you.  I understand the benefit of MVC, but the current application I'm working  with doesn't have that architecture. But I indeed watched tutorials and made dummy web apps using Lynda.com. I'll check Pluralsight as well. Thanks again.